# How to display price in product page with and without tax in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I found this workaround for version 1.6 here:
[How to display product price with and without tax at a time in product list for Prestashop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23237952/how-to-display-product-price-with-and-without-tax-at-a-time-in-product-list-for)

but the code for product-list.tpl changed a lot in 1.7

Is there a workaround for 1.7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

The file to edit is:
`psroot/themes/classic/templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl`

To display the price vat excl use this snippet (find the position in the html where do you want to display):

```
{Tools::displayPrice($product.price_tax_exc)}
```

PS: Pay attention to the rich snippet and SEO

Answer (score 0):

Since version `1.7.6`, `displayPrice` method is deprecated. Use `formatPrice` instead. For example in `templates/catalog/_partials/miniatures/_partials/product-prices.tpl`:

```
{block name='product_without_taxes'}
    {if $priceDisplay != 1}
        <p class="product-without-taxes">{l s='%price% tax excl.' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog' sprintf=['%price%' => Context::getContext()->currentLocale->formatPrice($product.price_tax_exc, $currency.iso_code)]}</p>
    {/if}
{/block}
```

Comment: Your route for me doennt exists. Also if I use @marsaldev route donesnt work. Any idea?